# How to append all values in lists using numpy and for-loop

Tags: list, dataframe, numpy, random-forest

I need to put all values in lists using Numpy. The code below is working but append only the last value and put it in list. I would like to know what is the problem in code below:

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

from sklearn.ensemble import forest

import sklearn.ensemble 

mse_train1 = []

mse_test1 = []

num_trees1 = []

for iter in range(10):

    num_trees1.append(iter)

    model.fit(train_set_RF, train_set_pred)

    y_train_predicted = model.predict(train_set_RF)

    y_test_predicted = model.predict(test_set_RF)

    mse_train = mean_squared_error(train_set_pred, y_train_predicted)

    np.append(mse_train1, iter)

    mse_test = mean_squared_error(test_set_pred, y_test_predicted)

    np.append(mse_test, iter)

    print("Iteration: {} Train mse: {} Test mse: {}".format(iter, mse_train, mse_test))

    model.n_estimators += 1
```

Comment: Do you mean `np.append(mse_test1, iter)` ?

Comment: I just need to append all values in 'mse_train' and ' mse_test' into  those two lists 'mse_train1 ' and 'mse_test1 '. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: `mse_train1.append(mse_train)` and `mse_test1.append(mse_test)` ? It's difficult to tell without a reproducible example.

Comment: yes, I mean that np.append(mse_test1, iter), but this is not work for me.

Comment: `np.append` is **not** list append and should not be used!